# Find an explicit solution of this equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, contour-integration

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Is it possible to solve  the equation

$$\cos{x}=\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(xy)}}{y^{1-\alpha}(y^{2\alpha}+1)}dy\quad (1).$$

It is very easy to compute
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y^{1-\alpha}(y^{2\alpha}+1)}dy=\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}.$$
Simply change variables $y^{\alpha}\rightarrow y$.
This shows that (1) has a solution, since the modulus of the right side is bounded by $\frac{1}{2}$. In fact the equation has infinitely many solutions by the periodicity of the cosine function. But, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: (+1) Interesting problem. You posted somewhere else a similar (easier one at that) problem. Just curious, where do this come from?

Comment: @ Oliver Díaz. Thanks. A long story. I will try to share more later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first remark, even if the integral can be computed, the solution will require some numerical method; remember that, up to quite recently, the equation $\cos(x)=x$ did not show explicit solution.

If $\alpha$ is the reciprocal of a natural number, there ar very complex results. Let
$$F(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(xy)}}{y^{1-\alpha}(y^{2\alpha}+1)}\,dy$$ Assuming $x>0$, a simple one is
$$F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(x)+C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi }} \right)
   (\sin (x)-\cos (x))-S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi }} \right)
   (\sin (x)+\cos (x))\right)$$ where appear Fresnel since an cosine integrals.

The function
$$G(x)=\cos(x)-F\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ shows, as usual, an infinite number of roots located close the $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$.

A first approximation will be
$$x_n=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2-\frac{\pi  (-1)^n \sqrt{2 n+1} \left(C\left(\sqrt{2 n+1}\right)-S\left(\sqrt{2 n+1}\right)\right)}{\pi  (-1)^n \sqrt{2 n+1} \left(C\left(\sqrt{2
   n+1}\right)+S\left(\sqrt{2 n+1}\right)\right)+\pi  (-1)^n \sqrt{2 n+1}-1}$$
which is quite decent
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution}\\
 0 & 1.3909739 &  1.3891919\\ 
 1 & 4.8094392 &  4.8096068\\ 
 2 & 7.7788933 &  7.7788193\\ 
 3 & 11.057851 &  11.057892\\ 
 4 & 14.082352 &  14.082324\\ 
 5 & 17.327928 &  17.327948\\ 
 6 & 20.375165 &  20.375150\\ 
 7 & 23.603812 &  23.603824\\ 
 8 & 26.664228 &  26.664218\\ 
 9 & 29.882198 &  29.882206\\ 
 10 & 32.951472 &  32.951465\\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

The simplest one is
$$F(1)=\frac 12 e^{-x}$$ which would give as a first extimate
$$x_n=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2+\frac{1}{1-2 (-1)^n e^{\pi  \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}}$$ which is almost exact after the second root.

Now, have a look
$$18\pi\,F\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=3 \pi  (\sinh (x)+3 \cosh (x))+$$
$$8 \sqrt{3} x^{5/3} \Gamma \left(-\frac{8}{3}\right) \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{4}{3},\frac{11}{6};\frac{x^2}{4}\right)-4
   \sqrt{3} \sqrt[3]{x} \Gamma \left(-\frac{4}{3}\right) \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{6};\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$$

Are you sure that you want to continue ?

Using the same procedure as above, for the monster given above
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution}\\
 0 & 1.3677200 &  1.3656718 \\
 1 & 4.8540487 &  4.8545462 \\
 2 & 7.7314241 &  7.7311063 \\
 3 & 11.104773 &  11.104773 \\
 4 & 14.035919 &  14.035919 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Medo. This is just the Taylor series around $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$. Notice that much better could be done using more terms and series reversion.